# AngularJS directive for Word Count not triggered on user selecting text and pressing delete/backspace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written a directive for my AngularJS app that counts the amount of words in a textarea and if it is lower than a determined threshold I set the `ng-valid` item to false. All is well however the word count doesn't seem to work when the user selects some or all the text in the textarea and then deletes the selected content using the backspace or delete button. How to I capture this event? My directive is below, I thought the binding to the `onmouseup` event would cover such a scenario:

```
    .directive('wordCount', function () {

        return {
            restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
            require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                // do nothing if no ng-model
                if (!ngModel) {
                    return;
                }

                // scope.minWordCount is taken from the scope!!!! We repeat this so put into reuseabe function
                if (!scope.minWordCount) {
                    return;
                }

                function checkWordCount() {

                    if (element[0].value === '') {
                        scope.wordCount = 0;
                    } else {
                        scope.wordCount = element[0].value.replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length;
                    }

                    // replace the numbers by finding the first space
                    scope.wordCountText = scope.wordCount + ' ' + scope.wordCountText.substr(scope.wordCountText.indexOf(' ') + 1);


                    if(scope.wordCount > scope.minWordCount - 1) {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('wordcount', true);
                    } else {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('wordcount', false);
                    }
                }


                var page = angular.element(window);

                page.bind('load', function () {
                    checkWordCount();
                });

                // Listen for change events to enable binding
                element.bind('blur keyup keydown keypress click change focus onmouseup', function () {
                    checkWordCount();
                });

            }
        };
    })
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you an easier way to do this, using the $viewChangeListeners property of ngModel.

Here is a working sample, hope it will help you

http://plnkr.co/edit/aZtl2hoEaXrkZCRAR9RH?p=preview

```
directive('wordCounter', function() {

    return {

     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function($scope, $node, attributes, controller) {

       function countWord(string) {
         return string.split(' ').length;
       }


       controller.$viewChangeListeners.push(function(){
         console.log(countWord(controller.$modelValue))
       })
     }


    }
  });
```

Comment: its working fine but what if I enter text like my,test,is failed . it will count one word only. is there any other way to count word which include(, . tab enter keys) to separate word count.

Comment: sure, you can use a regular expression to split the string.
`yourstring.split(/[\s\t,]/)`